# When I try to post a question on Stack Overflow, I get the error message "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length."

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, questions, asking-questions

When I click the "Post Your Question" button, an error "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length." I am confused since I am creating a question, not a comment.

Comment: Related Meta Stack Overflow question: [Can't post question because of error: "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416870/cant-post-question-because-of-error-comments-must-be-at-least-15-characters-i)

Comment: Would normally migrate this, but since there's already the same question on Meta SO, there's not much reason to do so.